# Application Insights for WebAPI how see requests per second

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

We are developing a WebApi2 REST API. Now I would like to see the API requests per second in a AI tile/section. There is a metric for ASP.NET request rate, but this is not showing any data for me. Any idea why this could be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the reason is with ASP.NET request rate not showing up, but if you have request data flowing into AI from this application you should be able to create a chart with Metric Explorer in Application Insights UI on Azure Portal:

- Pick "Request Rate (Rate)" metric in the settings and select the appropriate chart type.
- Then you can pin this chart to Azure dashboard or overview page in AI.

If AI data is not collected at all - it is slightly different topic.